# How to use S60 SDK with qt creator.it showing me Can't find any RVCTinstalltion

Tags: qt, symbian

Running build steps for project googlechat...

```
Starting: c:/qt/4.7.0/bin/qmake.exe C:/NokiaQtSDK/Examples/4.6/webkit/googlechat/googlechat.pro -r -spec symbian-abld 
WARNING: c:\NokiaQtSDK\Examples\4.6\webkit\googlechat\googlechat.pro:15: Unable to find file for inclusion \examples\symbianpkgrules.pri 
Exited with code 0.
Starting: C:/Nokia/devices/Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v0.9/epoc32/tools/make.exe -w 
C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v0.9\epoc32\tools\make.exe: Entering directory `C:/NokiaQtSDK/Examples/4.6/webkit/googlechat' 
bldmake bldfiles 
BLDMAKE ERROR: Can't find any RVCT installation. 
C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v0.9\epoc32\tools\make.exe: *** [ABLD.BAT] Error 1 
C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v0.9\epoc32\tools\make.exe: Leaving directory `C:/NokiaQtSDK/Examples/4.6/webkit/googlechat' 
Exited with code 2.
Error while building project googlechat (target: Symbian Emulator)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove ARM5 and ARM6 target from your bld.inf file. You have to do this before each build,
this is a bug with qmake and Symbian^3 SDK.

If you use Mobility APIs you also need to copy the epoc/include/mw to epoc/include/middleware for compiling successfully.