# error with Qt 4.6.2 & Symbian^3 SDK v0.8

Tags: qt, symbian

I meet the same error with Qt 4.6.2 & Symbian^3 SDK v0.8.

The problem happens when I execute the command "bldmake bldfiles"

BLDMAKE ERROR: Can't find any RVCT installation.

I am porting a existing Qt project(S60v5), which was developed using SDK Nokia_N97_SDK_v0.8.

There is no error when I using the Nokia_N97_SDK_v0.8 SDK to build the project.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use S60 SDK with qt creator.it showing me Can't find any RVCTinstalltion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896508/how-to-use-s60-sdk-with-qt-creator-it-showing-me-cant-find-any-rvctinstalltion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove ARM5 and ARM6 target from your bld.inf file. do this before each build, this is a bug with qmake and Symbian^3 SDK.